# Div with inside a text with font auto-adaptive to div's size

Tags: css, html, text, font-size

I'll tell you what I would do

I have to create a simple div with width: 100%

Inside I put text centered (vertically and horizontally)

I would like the text inside the div auto-amended the font size according to the size of the div

I hope I was clear

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar things have been asked around here. I myself had needed that once, and found no way of doing that accuarately with CSS only.

I ended up having a Javascript function that took each div and an inner paragraph with a predetermined `font-size` and reduced its font size until the paragraph had less width and height than its parent div.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/